# Number of installs of an android game

Tags: android, google-play, google-developers-console

I have a puzzle game on Google Play.
Developer console shows me current installs are 5 although I think they are much more than 5 as I have current 47 rates so they should be at least 47.

Comment: take a look at date on statistics page . Usually there is delay on number of counts by a day or two.

Comment: I see it and there is a delay as you said but by 3 days

Answer (score 0):

Try and install Google analytics and Google developers console to see more frequent and accurate results on your app

1. [Analytics](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.giant&hl=en)
2. [Play Cobsole](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/)